# Configuration file syntax

Tags: syntax, configuration-files

I'm developing software that will utilize a config file. I don't know many syntaxes or formats of config files. Here are the two I know:

(common with .conf files)

```
[section]
key=value
#comment
```

or (common with .ini)

```
key value
; comment
```

My interest is something versatile that's almost a language. Let's say

```
[Default]
Start = 0
End = 10
Speed = 1

[Section 3-6]
Speed = 2
```

This would act as an override. However this isn't any convention that I know of. Is there a common syntax that allows for this?

Comment: wow, 3 minutes have passed and no one suggested xml.

Comment: Heh, true, though I don't think that's an intuitive config file... maybe with a wizard hrm... post it as an answer. Though if you use a wizard, might as well use JSON

Comment: A wizard? You didn't say anything about requirements. Does this mean the file is frequently edited by non-technical persons?

Comment: even if technical... reading xml is unpleasant (maybe i'm just spoiled)

Comment: I use an executable Python file for a configuration file in some of my Python applications. This is _extremely_ versatile, so much so that it would be consider by many a security risk...

Comment: @martineau, your exec is opensource? got a git?

Comment: No, sorry. Doesn't matter though -- I just use Python's built-in [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile) function with custom `globals` and `locals` dictionaries (effectively namespaces). The latter is initially just an empty `dict` and the former I preload with only that which I want to be available to the file being executed. Anything that is defined during execution will, by default, be added to the `locals` dictionary passed which can be examined and used after the function returns.

Comment: You could add a comment at top to explain the conent of the file, which explains that subsequent sections/values override previous values. This is quite usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This once-valid answer is being voted down in 2020, so I edited it.

In 2011, I suggested you use an xml format. This was the de-facto standard then.

The configuration document could have looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<configuraton>
    <default>
        <start>0</start>
        <end>10</end>
        <speed>1</speed>
    </default>
    <section from="3" to="6">
        <speed>2</speed>
    </section>
</configuration>
```

There are many libraries to parse such files.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file#See_also), "the INI file format is a de facto standard for configuration files."

Comment: Why are there 2 minuses? I wasn't asking for any de facto standards. I was asking for a particular need I had with possible override of sub section.

Comment: XML is probably the worst thing you can do to users. It is complex to parse with computers and hard to read for humans and prone to errors.

Comment: Sorry. Didn’t want to startle you :)

Answer (score 19):

As of 2015, xml is no longer the de facto standard. Here are options.

[TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml)

```
# This is a TOML document.

title = "TOML Example"

[owner]
name = "Tom Preston-Werner"
dob = 1979-05-27T07:32:00-08:00

[servers]

  # tabs / spaces ok but not required
  [servers.alpha]
  ip = "10.0.0.1"
  dc = "eqdc10"
```

[YAML](https://yaml.org/)

```
%YAML 1.2
---
YAML: YAML Ain't Markup Language

Projects:
  C/C++ Libraries:
  - libyaml       # "C" Fast YAML 1.1
  - Syck          # (dated) "C" YAML 1.0
  - yaml-cpp      # C++ YAML 1.2 implementation
```

[CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson)

```
# Comments!!!

greatDocumentaries: [
    'earthlings.com'
    'forksoverknives.com'
]

importantFacts:
    # Multi-Line Strings! Without Quote Escaping!
    emissions: '''
        Livestock and their byproducts account for at least 32,000 million tons of carbon dioxide (CO2) per year, or 51% of all worldwide greenhouse gas emissions.
        '''
```

[JSON5](http://json5.org/) and [Human JSON](http://hjson.org/) - flexible json supersets

[Properties File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) - used by java programs